# RxSwift's scheduler is strange after switching

Tags: rx-swift

I'm facing a problem with RxSwift schedulers.

Production code like below,

```swift
class SomePresenter {

    let repository: SomeRepository
    let subscribeScheduler: ImmediateSchedulerType

    var list: [SomeEntity] = []

    let bag = DisposeBag()

    init(repository: SomeRepository,
         subscribeScheduler: ImmediateSchedulerType) {
        self.repository = repository
        self.subscribeScheduler = subscribeScheduler
    }

    func some() {
        repository
            .getSome()
            .subscribeOn(subscribeScheduler)
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(onSuccess: { [weak self] list in
                guard let self = self else {
                    return
                }
                self.list = list
            }) { error in
                fatalError()
            }.disposed(by: bag)
    }
}
```

and test code for that like below.

```swift
class researchRxTestFailedTests: XCTestCase {

    func testExample1() {
        let presenter1 = SomePresenter(repository: MockedSomeRepository(),
                                      subscribeScheduler: ConcurrentMainScheduler.instance)
        presenter1.some()
        XCTAssertEqual(presenter1.list.count, 2)
    }

    func testExample2() {
        let presenter2 = SomePresenter(repository: MockedSomeRepository(),
                                      subscribeScheduler: ConcurrentMainScheduler.instance)
        presenter2.some()
        XCTAssertEqual(presenter2.list.count, 2)
    }

    func testExample3() {
        let presenter3 = SomePresenter(repository: MockedSomeRepository(),
                                      subscribeScheduler: SerialDispatchQueueScheduler.init(qos: .default)) // Here is key!!
        presenter3.some()
        XCTAssertEqual(presenter3.list.count, 2)
    }

    func testExample4() {
        let presenter4 = SomePresenter(repository: MockedSomeRepository(),
                                      subscribeScheduler: ConcurrentMainScheduler.instance)
        presenter4.some()
        XCTAssertEqual(presenter4.list.count, 2)
    }

    func testExample5() {
        let presenter5 = SomePresenter(repository: MockedSomeRepository(),
                                      subscribeScheduler: ConcurrentMainScheduler.instance)
        presenter5.some()
        XCTAssertEqual(presenter5.list.count, 2)
    }

    class MockedSomeRepository: SomeRepository {
        func getSome() -> Single<[SomeEntity]> {
            return Single.just(
                [
                    SomeEntity(id: 100, name: "hoge"),
                    SomeEntity(id: 101, name: "fuga")
                ]
            )
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run this test code (not `randomize execution order`), I got failure like below.

[image]

So why this happens? 
I can understand `testExample3` fails, because its scheduler is background scheduler. 
But I couldn't understand why following test examples(`testExample4` and `testExample5`) fail even if those schedulers are main thread scheduler.

**NOTE**: If I switch to `ConcurrentMainScheduler` in `testExample3`, all tests passes.

Comment: This is actual sample code -> https://github.com/ushisantoasobu/researchRxTestFailed

Comment: why don't you try RxTest?

Comment: Could you tell me the way to write test code for "SomePresenter.swift" above with RxTest? @iWheelBuy